# WPF DataGrid проблема со скролом

Tags: wpf, datagrid

в окне DataGrid вложенный в ScrollViewer, последний немного шире. датагрид по высоте больше. Нужно чтобы датагрид скроллился, но это происходит только если поставить у него IsHitTestVisible="False" но при этом не работают заголовки колонок, не могу сортировать. скролл происходит если навести на область ScrollViewer свободную от DataGrid

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  Height="400">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgvNight" 
              Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="True" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
>
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ttl}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="МКБ" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt1}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="0-1" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt2}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="1-4" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt3}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="4-7" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста пример, который позволит нам воспроизвести эту проблему.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вы пытаетесь прокрутить весь контролл целиком? Ведь не лучше будет сделать как и везде, прокрутка содержимого?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  не могли бы пояснить?

Comment: Ну есть контрол (DataGrid), у него есть "шапка" и разные элементы после нее. Вы засовываете DataGrid в ScrollViewer, что заставит прокручиваться весь DataGrid целиком (с шапкой и элементами внутри). Как по мне это как то... странно. Уберите вы этот ScrollViewer и DataGrid сам добавит полосу прокрутки для своего содержимого, если элементы выше заданной высоты контрола.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ добавил свойства СanVerticallyScroll="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  и гриду и его родителю StackPanel. Удалил ScrollViewer. Без эффекта

Comment: Изначально там все и так включено как положено. Уберите все лишние свойства. Особенно IsHitTestVisible!

Comment: Вон, убрал [все лишние свойства](https://pastebin.com/2uF3Vg9S), результат [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42HzN.gif).

Comment: OMG. нужно было всего лишь выставить высоту у грида. проблема решена

Comment: Тут еще проблема в том, что вы поместили DataGrid в StackPanel. Внимание: **StackPanel выделяет контролу столько высоты сколько он просит**